# IOS/Objective-C: NSTimer without handler possible in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am trying to translate some Swift that uses at Timer to type out words for a news ticker effect into Objective -C.

In Swift, you can do something like:

```
    func type(string: String) {
        var wordArray  = ["Sox Win", "Verlander To Start", "Race Tightens"] // an array of strings
        var wordIndex = 0
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            self.textview.text.append(wordsArray[wordIndex])
            wordIndex += 1
            if wordIndex == wordArray.count {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in Objective-C, you typically see:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                      target: self
                      selector:@selector(update:)
                      userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
-(void) update:(NSTimer*)timer
{
int i=0;i<4;i++ {
NSLog(@"another second");
}
timer.invalidate;
timer = nil;
}
```

Using the handler, I can't figure out how to iterate the words in the array without creating the array over and over which obviously does not work.

```
- (void)updateView:(NSTimer *)timer
{
NSArray*items =@[@"item1", @"item2", @"item3", @"item4", @"item5"];
 for(int i=0;i<[items count];i++){
    self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByAppendingString:items[i]];
    if (i == [items count]) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
    }
}
```

Should I be doing something with userInfo or how can I use the time to update one word at a time?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It uses in fact `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:` (iOS10+) which has a block, translated in Swift as a Closure. Do you really want to no use the same method and use a `@selector()`?

Comment: You'd to create properties that can be retrieved (either @property of your object holding it), or as your said use userInfo with `wordArray` and `wordIndex`, etc. It's verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C supports the same block based `NSTimer` method. A translation of your Swift method would be:

```
- (void)type:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *wordArray = @[ @"Sox Win", @"Verlander To Start", @"Race Tightens" ];
    __block NSInteger wordIndex = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        // append wordsArray[wordIndex]
        wordIndex += 1;
        if (wordIndex == wordArray.count) {
            [timer invalidate];
        }
    }];
}
```

If for some reason you really wanted to use the selector based timer, you would need to store the array and index in instance variables. But that's the point of using this block-based solution - you avoid all of that extra work and additional method (for the selector).

Another approach is to use `dispatch_after`:

```
- (void)type:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *wordArray = @[ @"Sox Win", @"Verlander To Start", @"Race Tightens" ];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < wordArray.count; i++) {
        dispatch_after(i + 0.1, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // append wordsArray[i]
        });
    }
}
```

No timer required.